# How to iterate through the vertices in a polygonal mesh?

Tags: python, mesh, vertices

I have a mesh that I have created using data that I have. I have managed to load this mesh into blender using bpy.

I know I can iterate through all the polygons using something like this

```
for poly in mesh.polygons:
    for idx in poly.loop_indices:
        print(idx)
```

But what I really want is an index to the vertex for each polygon, so I can set a specific color from another file.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: poly.vertices gives you the vertices for each polygon.  However, from your question it sounds like you want something to uniquely identify each vertex.